# Get user id after save post

Tags: users

I want to get the ID of the user that has been updated by the admin in user's panel after the save_post, I have the following code but it shows nothing in the debug.log

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_save_post_function',10, 3 );
function my_save_post_function( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
    error_log($post_ID  );
    error_log( print_r( $post_ID  , true ) );
}
```

I also enable this in wp-config.php

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action `save_post` gets triggered after a post is saved, not after a user is saved. For this you need the action [`profile_update`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Action_Reference/profile_update).